# Convert flag into either 0xFF or 0, based on whether flag equals 1 or 0

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have a binary flag `f`, equal to either zero or one.
If equal to one, I would like to convert to `0xFF`, otherwise, to 0.

Current solution is  `f*0xFF`, but I would rather use bit twiddling to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just:

```
(unsigned char)-f
```

or alternately:

```
0xFF & -f
```

If `f` is already a `char`, then you just need `-f`.

This approach works because `-0 == 0` and `-1 == 0xFFFFF...`, so the negation gets you want you want directly, perhaps with some extra high bits set if `f` is larger than a `char` (you didn't say).

Remember though that compilers are smart. I tried all of the following solutions, and all compiled down to 3 instructions or less, and none had a branch (even the solution with a conditional):

#### Conditional

```
int remap_cond(int f) {
  return f ? 0xFF : 0;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
remap_cond:
        test    edi, edi
        mov     eax, 255
        cmove   eax, edi
        ret
```

So even the "obvious" conditional works well, in three instructions and a latency of 2 or 3 cycles on most modern x86 hardware, depending on `cmov` performance.

#### Multiplication

Your original solution of:

```
int remap_mul(int f) {
  return f * 0xFF;
}
```

Actually compiles into nice code that avoids the multiplication entirely, replacing it with a shift and subtract:

```
remap_mul:
        mov     eax, edi
        sal     eax, 8
        sub     eax, edi
        ret
```

This will generally take two cycles on machines with mov-elimination, and the `mov` would often be removed by inlining anyway.

#### Subtraction

As *corn3lius* pointed out, you can do some subtraction from `0x100` and a mask, like so:

```
int remap_shift_sub(int f) {
  return 0xFF & (0x100 - f);
}
```

This compiles to<sup>1</sup>:

```
remap_shift_sub:
        neg     edi
        movzx   eax, dil
        ret
```

So that's the best so far I think - a latency of 2 cycles on most hosts, and the `movzx` can often be eliminated by inlining<sup>2</sup> - e.g., since it could use the 8-bit register in a subsequent consuming instruction.

Note that the compiler has smartly eliminated both the masking operation (you could perhaps argue the `movzx` accounts for it), and the use of the `0x100` constant, because it understands that a simple negation does the same thing here (in particular, all the bits that differ between `-f` and `0x100 - f` are masked away by the `0xFF & ...` operation).

That leads directly to the following C code:

```
int remap_neg_mask(int f) {
  return -f;
}
```

which compiles down the exact same thing.

You can [play with all of this on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/EGdFxq).

---

<sup>1</sup> Except on `clang`, which inserts an extra `mov` to get the result in `eax` rather than generating it there in the first place.

<sup>2</sup> Note that by "inlining" I mean both real inlining the compiler does if you actually write this as a function, but also what happens if you just do the remapping operation directly at the place you need it without a function.

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed answer. Learned a lot. Here is a twist in my case : I will be using this bit manipulation on the GPU. Which doesn't like branches at all.

Comment: props for mentioning godbolt, hadn't heard of that.

Comment: @Jacko this is even safer in a shader, shader compilers are really hardcore when it comes to removing branches. For this case, AMD's shader compilers use `SETNE_DX10 \ CNDE_INT` (so a compare/conditional-move pair)

Comment: @harold thanks. This is actually for an OpenCL compute kernel. I am not sure how it handles branches. But, with bit manipulation, I don't need to worry :)

Answer (score 1):

```
value = 0xFF & ((1 << 16) - f )
```

If `f` is one, subtract it from `0x100` giving you `0xFF`; otherwise subtract 0 and bitmask with `0xFF` and get `0`.

*Too obvious?*

```
value = ( f == 1 ) ? 0xFF : 0;
```

Comment: Awesome! I want to avoid the second option, because it has a branch, and I want to avoid branches.

Comment: @Jacko it *might* be a branch. It may also be any of the platform-dependent tricks, such as `sbb al, al` (if the flag is in the carry flag), `neg al` (if the flag is 0/1 in `al`), etc. Check asm output.

Comment: Note that `1 << 16` is not `0x100` as you imply in your explanation